# iFrame that gets GET data from form loads wrong source

Tags: php, forms, iframe, target

So I have a site `example.com/search.php` which has an iFrame in it like so:

`<iframe src='http://anotherdomain.com/form.php' name='iframeform'></iframe>`

My site also has a sidebar with a little form that is supposed to pass data to the iFrame in `mydomain.com/search.php`. I used the forms `target` attribut for that like so:

`<form action="http://example.com/search.php" target="iframeform" method="get">`

When I submit the form the page `example.com/search.php` is loaded as expected. However, the iFrame does not load the external URL, but instead it also loads `example.com/search.php`. The iFrame within the iFrame loads the external URL.

So what I would like to achieve is to submit my sidebar form and send the data to the iFrame. But the iFrame loads the wrong source, the same site instead of the external URL.

**EDIT:** to clear this up a bit. A form on `site1.php` sends data to `site2.php`. On `site2.php` is an iFrame with its source set to an external URL `example.com/search.php`. I want the data from `site1.php` to be passed to the iFrame in `site2.php`; I used the form's target attribute for that.

When I submit the form the browser loads `site2.php`, as you would except, but the iFrame ALSO loads `site2.php` instead of the external URL, which doesn't really makes sense to me. So what I get is `site2.php` in the browser, which has an iFrame that loads `site2.php` which again has an iFrame...

Comment: as far as I understand, you can't use "target" to target elements on the same page. Its more for other windows. I think you might have to use a javascript solution for something like this.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Do you mean that when the form is submitted, the `iframe` should load `anotherdomain.com/search.php` instead of `example.com/search.php`?